# Is it possible to have constructor with the same number of variables and data type?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading, constructor-overloading

I just want to know if we can use overloading constructor with the same number of variables, same data types with the different variables.

```
Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String jobRole){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.jobRole = jobRole;
    this.sex = "N/A";
    this.status = "N/A";
    this.ethnicity = "N/A";
}

Employee(String sex, String status, String ethnicity){
    this.firstName = "N/A";
    this.lastName = "N/A";
    this.jobRole = "N/A";
    this.sex = sex;
    this.status = status;
    this.ethnicity = ethnicity;
}
```

I tried to instantiate these, but it gives an error "cannot resolve constructor".

```
    Employee e = new Employee( "juan", "dela cruz", "programmer");
    Employee e1 = new Employee("Male", "Single", "Filipino");
```

It works if i remove the other constructor and replace it with a different data type.

```
    Employee e = new Employee( "juan", "dela cruz", "programmer");
    Employee e2 = new Employee(2023, 19, 2000);
```

can you explain this and what ways can we fix this.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will certainly result into `Ambiguity` as compiler won't be able to find out to which constructor to invoke since all are String arguments.

You can merge all the arguments in one constructor if the all the fields are class members!

**Quoting a definition from the website below for your reference !**

> Constructor overloading in Java is a technique of having more than one constructor with different parameter lists. They are arranged in a way that each constructor performs a different task. They are differentiated by the compiler by the number of parameters in the list and **their types**.

[https://www.javatpoint.com/java-constructor#:~:text=Constructor%20overloading%20in%20Java%20is,the%20list%20and%20their%20types](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-constructor#:%7E:text=Constructor%20overloading%20in%20Java%20is,the%20list%20and%20their%20types).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because it cannot decide which constructor for the instantiation should be used. Here is the specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html

> 8.4.2. Method Signature
>
> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.
>
> Two method or constructor declarations M and N have the same argument types if all of the following conditions hold:
>
> They have the same number of formal parameters (possibly zero)
>
> They have the same number of type parameters (possibly zero)
>
> Let A1, ..., An be the type parameters of M and let B1, ..., Bn be the type parameters of N. After renaming each occurrence of a Bi in N's type to Ai, the bounds of corresponding type variables are the same, and the formal parameter types of M and N are the same.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> m2 has the same signature as m1, or
>
> the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:
How would Java know which function you're referring to when calling Employee() with three string parameters? The other one works because of "function overloading" - Java would know to call the constructor with three int parameters instead of the three strings one.

This looks like introductory Java class content. You could probably find the answers in your textbook :)